# How to break down a mat file, which has 60 of 4 by 4 matrices in it, to 60 distinct matrices with different names using a for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a mat file (AA) in which there are 60 matrices. I want to store the matrices into single matrix and save them with distinct names in a for loop. But I get error that I do not know how to get rid of. Do you have any ideas?

```
AA = randn(4,4,60);  % this is the matrix w/ 60 matrices in it
for i = 1:60
BB = zeros[4,4, length(AA)];  % pre-allocation
BB(:,:,i) = AA(:,:,i);
filename = ['BB-' num2str(i), 'mat'];  % rename the file to have different matrices
save(filename, 'BB')
end
```

But it does not work the way that I want!

Comment: pre-allocation should be **pre** = before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do this:

```
AA = randn(4,4,60);  % this is the matrix w/ 60 matrices in it
for i = 1:60
    BB = AA(:,:,i);
    filename = ['BB-' num2str(i), 'mat'];  % rename the file to have different matrices
    save(filename, 'BB')
end
```

No need for the pre-allocation of `BB`.

Comment: you forgot the dot in `.mat`

Comment: oh, uh, you forgot it *too*, rather. :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I was not sure what is the exact name the OP wanted to give his files, so I decided leaving it as is, and just make it work.

Comment: hahah, yes. I just thought I'd preempt the "why are my filenames wrong" question :p